# Design with two similar algorithm about code duplication and testing?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, architecture, moq

I'm developing a programme to manipulate costs history and eventually a prediction.

The problem I've faced is that I want to calculate modifiers which will be use on the costs history to remove season variance. I need two diffent ways to calculate them and those two are nearly the same except places where it will be a multiplication instead of an addition.

An example would be :

```
    private void CalculAndSumEveryPeriodeModifier()
    {
        List<double> averages = MovingAverage.Averages;

        for (int i = 0; i < averages.Count; ++i)
        {
            averages[i] = costsList[i + NbPeriode / 2] / averages[i] // Division changed to substraction
            modifiers[((i + NbPeriode / 2) % NbPeriode)] += averages[i];
        }
    }
```

I've made an attempt with an abstract class having a private abstract method that takes two doubles. The concrete classes can then implement this method to divide or subtract the doubles at certain points in the algorithm.

The problem with this approach is that I don't know how to unit test it. Can I test the abstract class with the moq framework if yes how? Else I need to test both concrete class which will duplicate code since the tests will be the same.

Is there a way to unit test my attempt or is there a better approach?

Kevin

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not factor out the common code of the two unit test methods into a shared method?

```
private int[] input = new int[] { 2, 8, 6, 1, 5, 1, 7, 5, 2, 4 };

[TestMethod]
public void TestVariantA() 
{
    var obj = new ConcreteA();
    DoTest(obj, input, new int[] { -2.8, 3, 1.4, -3.2, 1 });
}


[TestMethod]
public void TestVariantB() 
{
    var obj = new ConcreteB();
    DoTest(obj, input, new int[] { 0.2632, 1.7500, 1.3397, 0.2381, 1.2500 });
}

private void DoTest(AbstractType obj, int input, int expected)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Interresting, but the methods won't necessary return the same result for different concrete classes so it can't be tested by the exact same  test method and I will be testing 2 classes in the same test file which I think is not recommended.

Comment: What about also supplying the expected result to `DoTest`?

Comment: I'm not sure if it is what you meant but, let say I have a list of value : { 2, 8, 6, 1, 5, 1, 7, 5, 2, 4 }
The result for the stragegy using addition would be : { -2.8, 3, 1.4, -3.2, 1 }
The result for the stragegy using multiplication would be : { 0.2632, 1.7500, 1.3397, 0.2381, 1.2500 }
It is just because some set of values are better estimated using one of the 2 methodes.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: Now I better understand what you wanted to do with your answer. It is realy interresting in fact. If I need to create other subClass I just need to add a test with the result of the new subclass. I just want to know if it is okay to test all the subClass in the abstractClassTest file?

Comment: Yes you can test these methods of all derived subclasses using this method.  Of course if a new subclass provided a new estimation method not available in the (abstract) base class, you would have to modify this to allow for that new method.